# Why was the Service Module Retained?

Tags: apollo-program

After the Apollo 13 explosion, the service module was retained almost until re-entry. Why was this if it was just dead weight?

Comment: Just see Why wasn't the Apollo 13 Service Module jettisoned until hours before reentry? https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15305  
This question was asked already and has a good answer.

Comment: It is a very good question! It seems it's been asked before and there'a a good answer. Welcome to stackexchange, [take the tour](https://space.stackexchange.com/tour) and ask something new - check to see if it's been asked before though!

Comment: So long as they don't use their engine what does weight matter?