# Did the service module in Apollo 13 do anything useful after the explosion, so that keeping it attached was important?

Tags: apollo-13

I realize they didn't know what happened so probably didn't know that there was such extensive damage. However, they didn't eject the service module. Why was that? Did it serve some useful purpose still? Were they just not ready for it?

Comment: Regardless of everything else, better to have it and not need it, than to need it and not have it.

Comment: From this [related question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15305/why-wasnt-the-apollo-13-service-module-jettisoned-until-hours-before-reentry): it seems the primary reason was to protect the reentry heat shield.

Comment: Ah understood, it is a duplicate

Comment: It does not mention that the high gain radio antenna was located on the service module. Was that a factor?