# Are there any free return trajectories for a manned Mars flyby mission between 2018 and 2024?

Tags: mars, trajectory, interplanetary, flyby, free-return

I am looking for a mission profile including the delta-v for burns for an interplanetary mission to Mars. I have been unable to find any free return trajectories between 2018 and 2024, are there any?

Comment: Scroll down to [my answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/13368/12038) to [this question](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/13366/12038) and you will find a link to a paper discussing possible free-return trajectories.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't just link to the paper directly... [here is a link](http://www.marsjournal.org/contents/2007/0002/files/wooster_mars_2007_0002.pdf).

Comment: There's a free-return launch opportunity on May 10 2018, and you can find others with [NASA's Trajectory Browser](http://trajbrowser.arc.nasa.gov/traj_browser.php?maxMag=25&maxOCC=4&chk_target_list=on&target_list=Mars&mission_class=roundtrip&mission_type=flyby&LD1=2018&LD2=2024&maxDT=2.0&DTunit=yrs&maxDV=7.0&min=DV&wdw_width=-1&submit=Search#a_load_results) tool (link is an example query that will return the trajectory for mentioned date, and see others with Post-Injection ΔV of 0 or close to it - tool allows you to sort results by columns). Technically, Mars cyclers are also free return.

Comment: Note that a "free return" isn't really free. You have a much higher departure $\Delta V$ or $C_3$ than a normal Mars transfer trajectory.